# Calico between virtual machines as Kubernetes nodes

Tags: kubernetes, vsphere, hypervisor, calico

I have a kubernetes cluster of some virtual machines running on top of Vsphere. I deployed Calico IP-IP plugin for connectivity and every thing is Ok. My questions are :
1) As calico performs BGP routed between the nodes , Does that also happen in the IPIP case or the flow is only Full mesh IPIP tunnels.
2) If there is BGP routes --- how can i check them ? and how were they advertised through the hypervisor ?
3) If not... how does the packet flow go between pods in my case ?

I tried to check the calicoctl results but no peers.
Some of Ip route results  : 
192.168.0.0/24 via 172.16.5.226 dev tunl0 proto bird onlink 
192.168.2.0/24 via 172.16.5.228 dev tunl0 proto bird onlink

Answer (score 0):

1) If by **IPIP** you mean node-to-node peering, then yes, it's [configurable](https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.5/usage/configuration/bgp)

```
calicoctl config set nodeToNodeMesh off
```

> For large-scale deployments, or for deployments where you require a
>   more specific BGP topology (e.g., peering with ToR switches) the full
>   node-to-node mesh should be disabled and explicit BGP peers configured
>   for your Calico nodes. A BGP peer may be configured in your Calico
>   network as a global BGP peer or a per-node BGP peer

2) List a routing table `route -n`
The direct routes are set up by a Calico agent named Felix when it is asked to provision connectivity for a particular workload. A BGP client (such as BIRD) then notices those and distributes them – perhaps via a route reflector – to BGP clients running on other hosts

3) [Calico packets flow](https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.5/reference/architecture/data-path)

Comment: Sorry. I mean in my case where the virtual machines are communicating through hypervisor,  and IPIP is enabled . Is there still BGP peering  between the Virtual machines or not ?

Comment: @Sam yes, but it's consistent with Calico only when host's route next hop IP represents the local hypervisor.